# Выдает ошибку ".unshift is not a function"

Tags: javascript

Выдает ошибку

> post.unshift is not a function

Подскажите как исправить?

```js
var main = {
"posts":[
 {
  "img": "images/avatar.jpg",
  "time": "12",
  "text":  "Lorem ",
  "link": "Obara Harama"
 },
 {
  "img": "images/avatar.jpg",
  "time": "12",
  "text":  "Lorem ",
  "link": "Obara Harama"
 }
];


}
function localjson(){
 if(!localStorage.LocalStorage){
  var Local_Json = JSON.stringify(main);
  localStorage.setItem('LocalStorage', Local_Json);
  var Returned_Json = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('LocalStorage'));
  return Returned_Json;
 }
 else if(localStorage.LocalStorage){
   var Returned_Json = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('LocalStorage'));
  return Returned_Json; 
 }
};


function post() {
 $.each(localjson().posts, function(i, post){ 
  post.unshift(
  {
   "img": "images/avatar.jpg",
   "time": 'format_date',
   "text": ($('.post_bar').val()),
   "link": "Jason Stathem"
  }
   );
 });
};
```

Весь  [Код](http://codepen.io/Brave_Lime/pen/PzzwXm?editors=0010)

Comment: Вы уверены, что параметр **post** имеет тип массив?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko , я дополнил! Благодарю.

Comment: Думаю нужно сделать различные названия функции `post()` и аргумента function(i, **post**). Ну и убедиться, что в аргумент post входит объект, с функцией unshift

Comment: @Doofy увы, не помогло :( Спасибо.

Comment: Поскольку вы задали новый вопрос, то, наверное, тут уже все ясно? Отметьте ответ, который вам помог, такой зеленой галочкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете `each` из **jQuery**. Метод `each` проходит по всем элементам массива **posts**, вызывает callback функции, где первым параметром передает индекс элемента массива, а вторым параметров **элемент массива** (в вашем случае параметр **post**).

Получается, Вы пытаетесь выполнить метод `unshift` на элементе массива (объекте). Естественно, такого метода нет.

Возможно, вы хотели сделать что-то вроде этого?

```
function post() {
    var posts = localjson().posts;
    posts.unshift(
    {
        "img": "images/avatar.jpg",
        "time": 'format_date',
        "text": ($('.post_bar').val()),
        "link": "Jason Stathem"
    }
    );
};
```

Comment: Ошибка пропала, но добавление не происходит.  Да и напрямую, тогда, можно написать  `function post(){ localjson().posts.unshift({...`  Но, Спасибо!

Comment: Где не происходит добавление? Покажите весь код или создайте jsfiddle.

Comment: Прошу (http://codepen.io/Brave_Lime/pen/PzzwXm) - Спасибо Большое!

Comment: Извините, в Вашем codepen нету html разметки вообще никакой. Данное сообщество помогает решить проблему, а не писать за Вас код. Пожалуйста, добавьте html в Ваш codepen.io/Brave_Lime/pen/PzzwXm.

Comment: Done!  (http://codepen.io/Brave_Lime/pen/PzzwXm) :) Суть проста, добавление комментариев, которые будут в localStorage. Спасибо.

Comment: @Brave_Lime, если вы не сохраняете результат в localStorage, логично что он в него не добавится

Comment: @Grundy ,так  `unshift` это  _добавление_ в начало массива.

Comment: @Brave_Lime, ага, в массив и добавляется, к localStorage - не имеет никакого отношения

Comment: @Grundy Понял! Спасибо большое ♥

Comment: Как видно из Вашего кода на codepen, у Вас имеется один серьезный недостаток - смешевания `angular` c `jQuery`, Это очень, **очень** плохая практика. Если Вы и дальше так будете продолжать, то столкнетесь с множеством проблем. Делайте ваш проект или на  `angular` или на `jQuery`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Спасибо, учту!